# Does a repository layer necessitate not depending on database IDs in the rest of the code?

Tags: design-patterns, repository-pattern

So, the repository layer, as I understand it, the whole idea is that you could quickly and easily swap out one solution for another.  Say, I want to switch from MySQL to MongoDB.  All I need to worry about is writing a new repository layer.

So far, so good.

The problem is, MySQL will (most likely, in practice) use integers as primary keys, and MongoDB will use strings. Or maybe I want my repository layer to point to a web service, and who knows what kind of IDs they use...

So in order to give my repository layer a future-proof interface, I can't have methods like the following:

```
EmployeeRepository.getById(int id)
```

or

```
EmployeeRepository.getById(string id)
```

So what's a person to do?  Always use a string (or an object??) and just let the repository layer cast or convert it however it needs to?

Or should an application's models have their own internal ID scheme which is completely separate from the database's ID scheme, and you always fetch on that ID?   Something like:

```
EmployeeRepository.getByInternalId(int id)
```

What is the best practice here?

Comment: I'd treat them as strings. Treating IDs as integers (even if they appear to be ints) might lead to problems when for instance crossing a 32-bit limit...

Answer (score 0):

> So, the repository layer, as I understand it, the whole idea is that you could quickly and easily swap out one solution for another

No. The idea is to abstract the data layer to reduce compexity and code coupling. Instead of throwing everything togehter in one class you get two classes with more destinct responsibilites.

Switching from one type of data layer to another one is not trivial, even if you use repositories.

However. You can decide to use one kind of data layer in one repository (for instance vanilla ADO.NET) and another type of data layer in another repository (like Entity Framework). The point is that you can adapt your repositories after each specific use case. And that without affecting any other code.

> The problem is, MySQL will (most likely, in practice) use integers as primary keys, and MongoDB will use strings.

You are approaching the problem from the wrong way. Do the users of your application use the key? Do it has to be in a specific format? Or are the DB generated keys OK? If so, use whatever format the DB uses.

If you have to switch from MySQL to Mongo later you'll still have a lot to work to do (like moving from table relations to documents).

Comment: Ideally, the users of the application do not care about the key.  For dealing with relations, though, I still can't decide on what's best.  Do models know about each other?  Should I be able to say "book.Author.Name" or should I have to say (authorRepository.getByBookId(book.ID)).Name?  In the latter situation, the application does care about the database ID.  In the former, the models do need to be some kind of entities which can automatically relate to each other, in which case: are they eagerly loaded? How many objects deep? Or are they lazily loaded? How?

Comment: I prefer working with ids. It gives you better control of what is changed and when.